# Using output of iterate files as input for merge tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, merge, iterator

I am using trying to use an iterator to run through and folder of shapefiles and add them as input to the merge tool in ArcMap ModelBuilder. Something seems amiss; when I connect the iterate output file to the merge tool in ModelBuilder, it doesn't seem to take.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: I want to project all shapefile before merge but i cant do that

Comment: What am i doing? I added project but it cant do merge after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First setup [Iterate Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Classes/00400000000r000000/) to loop through all your feature classes in a workspace, this will feed them *one at a time* into your next process, but if you put [Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000005000000) as the next step in your process it will 'clump' all the individual feature classes into a cohesive input for Merge..

[image]

This workflow produced a merged feature class from *all* the feature classes in the workspace Area11_14.

Comment: Although this model _will work_ I would say it is very inefficient. Merge will run as many times as the iterator loops. Merge only needs to run once taking a list of inputs. The iterator and collects tool need to be in a sub-model with Output Values exposed as a parameter then this entire model sits in a master model feeding into a single merge tool. Performance will be significantly better.

Comment: I agree @Hornbydd, it is inefficient, it would make it work better by making a sub-model for processes up to *collect events* but thought at the time that a 2-step process would complicate the solution to the point where the OP would have difficulty following it.

Comment: I did feel like I was telling you [how to suck eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_grandmother_to_suck_eggs)! Thought if anyone reads the comment that they may take it to the next level and do it as a sub-model.

Comment: Agreed, or even better as a script in python, this is one of those instances that is tricky in model builder but so much easier in python. If anyone is reading this post note the comments and be inspired to try a submodel or have a go at python scripting (hint arcpy.ListFeatureClasses https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000023000000 and the associated examples)